# Stop action propagation within a form using Jquerymobile, Knockout.js?

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, form-submit, stoppropagation

So, I have this issue about performing two actions at the very same time. 
One of the actions is an AJAX call which consumes a webservice and do some stuff to save data on the server, the other action is to return to a view where there's a list.

My code just follows the href but doesn't perform the binding SUBMIT.
I was told that to do what I want I need to "stop the propagation of the action" but I don't know how. Would you mind giving me some tips? Here's the code:

```
<form data-bind="submit: updateData" method="post" data-ajax="false">
  <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
   <center>
     <h2> Save changes? </h2>
     <input type="submit" name:"submit" data-inline="true">
   </center>
  </div>
</form>
```

This question is based upon this one -> [How to perform a Knockout.js action before following an <Href>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223618/how-to-perform-a-knockout-js-action-before-following-an-href/24223751#24223751)  I was doing in a different way before but then I changed it to a form. However, none of these so worked out to me.

Comment: how are you loading a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
<form data-bind="submit: updateData" method="post" data-ajax="false">
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
        <center>
            <h2> Save changes? </h2>
            <input type="submit" name:"submit" data-inline="true">
        </center>
    </div>
</form>

self.UpdateData = function(){
    if(self.AjaxRequest()){
        //do other action
        //  $('some id').trigger('click');
    }
}
self.AjaxRequest = function(){
    var status = false
    $.jax({
        ...,
        success : function(){
            status = true
        }
    })
    return status
}
```